# Asynchronous serial communication thread options

Tags: c#

I have a serial connection to a device that I want to periodically monitor at a frequency of 1 to 1/10 Hz (not decided yet).

I would like the communication to be non-blocking, and thus I have decided to put the communication in a thread of some kind and let the main application receive data via events fired from the thread.

I was thinking about making a thread at application start that sends and receives data continuously. The thread empties a queue containing commands to send to the device, and then listen for response firing an event when a response is complete.
The thread is put to sleep when no commands are in the queue, and woken when commands enter the queue.

Is this a good way of doing it?
I was thinking about maybe using some of established features of the framework, like BackgroundWorker or Task, since these might have advantages over what I'm doing.
Maybe there are other and better ways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't frequent enough to justify burning up an expensive resource like a Thread.  Use a System.Timers.Timer or System.Threading.Timer (better) instead.  Write the device query command in the callback.  Use the SerialPort.DataReceived event to receive the response and fire the event.  Now everything runs on cheap threadpool threads.

Answer (score 0):

I found http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/e36193cd-a708-42b3-86b7-adff82b19e5e/ which explains a bit more of the architecture of SerialPort.